# How to calculate log-loss for the trained model?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am building a ML pipeline for logistic regression.

```
val lr = new LogisticRegression()
lr.setMaxIter(100).setRegParam(0.001)

val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(geoDimEncoder,clientTypeEncoder,
               devTypeDimIdEncoder,pubClientIdEncoder,tmpltIdEncoder,
               hourEncoder,assembler,lr))

val model = pipeline.fit(trainingDF)
```

Now, when the model is trained, I want to see the probabilities for the training set and compute certain validation parameters like log-loss. But, I am unable to find this using "model".

The only thing I could find everywhere is

```
model.transform(testDF).select(....)
```

How to get the metrics using the trained set for training set validation?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following ways, should work for you:

```
val lr = new LogisticRegression()
  .setMaxIter(10)
  .setRegParam(0.3)
  .setElasticNetParam(0.8)

val lrModel = lr.fit(data)

val trainingSummary = lrModel.summary

// Obtain the objective per iteration.
val objectiveHistory = trainingSummary.objectiveHistory
println("objectiveHistory:")
objectiveHistory.foreach(loss => println(loss))
```